# C# is showing HTML as plain text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In a cshtml file I am using a string defined in a Controller (processed by the model):

**Controller:**

```
namespace Site.Controllers
{
    public class PController : Controller    
    {
        public static P P1 = new P("<p>This is a paragraph</p>");
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(P1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class P(string paragraph)
{
    public String Paragraph { get; set; }
    public P(string paragraph ="")
    {
        Paragraph = paragraph;
    }
}
```

**CSHTML:**

```
@Site.Controllers.PController.P1.Paragraph
```

The paragraph in the CSHTML results as `<p>This is a paragraph</p>` instead of

This is a paragraph

How do I get the HTML to be handled like HTML?

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw(P1.Paragraph)` in your View

Comment: Or use a property of type `MvcHtmlString` in your `P` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.Raw(Site.Controllers.PController.P1.Paragraph)
```

This method creates an instance of HtmlString.

It represents an HTML-encoded string that should be used as is.

Then it wraps this instance and presents it as HTML markup.

Comment: An explanation might help.